# Check the method in project

Tags: c#, rar

I am trying to debug code from https://nunrar.codeplex.com/. In branch DOCUMENTATION -> Basic Usage there is the following code:

```
RarArchive archive = RarArchive.Open(source);
foreach (RarArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
{
    string path = Path.Combine(destination, Path.GetFileName(entry.FilePath));
    entry.ExtractToFile(path);
}
```

Well.. I 've downloaded source code, find `RarArchiveEntry` class and started to looking for method `ExtractToFile()`, but there isn't any method there neither in class, nor in project!
Please help me to find this method or method which i can call to look through how this programm can unpack rar files step-by-step?

Comment: Have you tried using SharpCompress, as suggested in big letters on that site?

Comment: **"SharpCompress is the future for NUnrar "**

Comment: Nope, i thought that code on that site is enough for me...I start to look through it now! But it still very strange that i can't find this method...

Comment: is RarArchiveEntry inherited from another class?

Comment: yes, from `RarEntry`

Comment: Documentation is obsolete, use `WriteToFile` instead of `ExtractToFile`. Or better follow @JonSkeet 's advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the documentation is obsolete and the name of the method was changed, there is an extension method found in [RarArchiveEntry.Exensions.cs](https://nunrar.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#NUnrar/Archive/RarArchiveEntry.Extensions.cs) called `WriteToFile`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Extract to specific file
/// </summary>
public static void WriteToFile(this RarArchiveEntry entry, string destinationFileName, ExtractOptions options = ExtractOptions.Overwrite)
{
    entry.WriteToFile(destinationFileName, new NullRarExtractionListener(), options);
}
```

Comment: Big Thanks! So now i call it from `main` and look through the code step-by-step :)